# ffmpeg video filters on each input video from txt input-file using stream_loop

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the below command to loop a number of video clips over the duration of an audio track:

`ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -f concat -i input.txt -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -shortest output.mp4`

Where input.txt looks like this:

```
file '1.mp4'
file '2.mp4'
file '3.mp4'
file '4.mp4'
file '5.mp4'
... 
file 'n.mp4'
```

I would like to add a fade in and fade out effect every time a new "clip" is mixed in. I have seen a few examples where the input files must be explicitly referenced in the effects chain. But since the number of videos in input.txt can vary it would be great to be able to add the same effect over and over again.

Comment: If it's OK to do separate fade in's and fade out's, call ffmpeg on each video to create the faded video `1_faded.mp4` etc. then do the command in your post with those files. If you must crossfade, you need to input them separately.

Comment: Yeah I guess that's the best option for now. Thanks for responding.